# why string declaration terminates the program in VScode?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode in windows with mingw. I have installed the C/C++ extension and properly configured the **Intellisense mode** and **tasks.json** (I followed this tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-helloworldcpp). Everything works fine until I use string. I am able to use other data types and containers without any problem.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"working";
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

The program terminates without printing anything, though it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: You didn't `#include <string>`

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- Use the proper headers, not this one.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073).

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yeah I am pretty sure that the program terminated. I am using Powershell terminal and I can see the next command line.

Comment: @AdrianMole, thank you. I learnt something. As far as I understand, the problem may arise if the header is incompatible with the compiler. But the other functions are working well. It would be nice if you elaborate

Comment: I also tried using `#include<string>` and `#include<iostream>` instead of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Still the situation remains the same